# Doxygen complains about overloaded functions that take same template but with different template parameter

Tags: c++, doxygen

[Edited to provide a minimal set to reproduce the issue.]

I have C++ code similar to this (file.h):

```
namespace xxx {
  template< typename T >
  class Array {};

  using sint = std::ptrdiff_t;
  using uint = std::size_t;
  using dfloat = double;
  using IntegerArray = Array< xxx::sint >;
  using UnsignedArray = Array< xxx::uint >;
  using FloatArray = Array< xxx::dfloat >;
}

/// \brief A namespace
namespace yyy {
namespace {

  /// \brief A function
  inline out* function( xxx::UnsignedArray const& in ) {}

  /// \brief A function
  inline out* function( xxx::IntegerArray const& in ) {}

  /// \brief A function
  inline out* function( xxx::FloatArray const& in ) {}

  /// \brief A class
  class AAA {
    public:
      /// \brief A class method
      out* function( xxx::BBB const& bbb ) {}
};
}}
```

The Doxyfile is:

```
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = out
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
INPUT                  = .
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.h
```

Doxygen complains with:

```
Searching for member function documentation...
/Users/cris/tmp/doxygenissue/file.h:25: warning: no matching class member found for 
  out *anonymous_namespace file yyy::anonymous_namespace{file.h}::yyy::h::function(xxx::IntegerArray const &in)

/Users/cris/tmp/doxygenissue/file.h:28: warning: no matching class member found for 
  out *anonymous_namespace file yyy::anonymous_namespace{file.h}::yyy::h::function(xxx::FloatArray const &in)
```

It doesn't seem to see the 2nd and 3rd functions. Only the first one shows up in the documentation. The anonymous namespace is needed to generate this error, as is the class with a method with the identical name.

Does anybody know a workaround? Besides changing the name of the class method, that is...

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Which specific settings do you have in yout doxygen configuration (Doxyfile) file? Did you try to make a minimal example to test it which you can also share here?

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.13 on MacOS, installed through HomeBrew. I'm working on a minimal set, I'll update the question in a little bit.

Comment: Also, without the anonymous namespace or the AAA class no errors are shown, but all three functions are seen as identical, their documentation is merged. If I define the `xxxArray` types using a builtin type as the template argument, then all three functions are documented separately.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with standard C++ classes (not templates) and overloaded functions in an unnamed namespace. So I suspect there is a bug. The documentation of the base class appears instead of the specific version of the overloaded function. If I don't document the overloaded function, I don't get the error and the function is _properly_ (i.e. properly but not specifically) documented with the base class docs.

Comment: @albert FYI, I found a [bug report](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/2403) on github about this problem. It's still happening in 1.8.11 and since the bug is still open, I would imagine it has not been worked on.

Comment: @AlexisWilke An open issue does not always mean that it has not been solved (might have been solved by means of another issue). You mention 1.8.11 an  this is from December 30 2015, the latest release is 1.8.15 and is from December 27 2018 so a lot of things might have changed (and even in the master / development version a lot of things might have been fixed). Anonymous parts are always a bit difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a rather ugly way to make it work until the bug gets fixed in Doxygen. It seems to work at least for my case. I suppose it affects some links, though, but at this point I think I prefer to get the expected description for each function than having proper links and namespace names.

I thought about the fact that Doxygen accepts preprocessor options which can be used to add a Doxygen specific `#define`. Here is my `doxygen.h` header:

```
#ifndef DOXYGEN_HPP
#define DOXYGEN_HPP

#ifdef DOXYGEN
#define no_name             doxygen
#else
#define no_name
#endif

#endif
```

As we can see, I defined a macro named `no_name` and when I *compile* with Doxygen I set it to `doxygen` otherwise it remains empty.

Now in my C++ files I do:

```
...
namespace no_name
{
    // static code goes here
    ...
} // no name namespace
...
```

So now when compiling with `g++`, I don't get a name as expected. When *compiling* with Doxygen, however, the namespace is given a name: `doxygen` and I do not get that error anymore.

For this magic to work, you also need to tweak your doxy file. Here are the relevant options:

```
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
PREDEFINED             = DOXYGEN=1
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = no_name
```

You may also need to fix the include path. It will be very important that the `doxygen.h` file gets included. I have CMake so it's easy for me:

```
INCLUDE_PATH           = @CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR@
```

At this point I've not seen anything breaking badly. So I am guessing it's a nice intermediate solution.

One other thing, make sure that `INHERIT_DOCS` is `NO` because by default it's `YES` and that means you'd still get the base class description.

Comment: This is a pretty clever workaround! Thanks! My errors went away when I converted the various `function(xxx::Array<type> const& in)` into a single templated function. That wasn't really a workaround, just a sensical simplification of my code, hence I didn't mention it here.

Answer (score 0):

As you are overloading a function, you should use /overload keyword , to add documentation for overloaded function.

```
template<typename T> class Array;
using UnsignedArray = Array<unsigned>
using IntegerArray = Array<int>
using FloatArray = Array<float>

 /// \overload brief A function
void function(UnsignedArray const&);

/// \overload brief A function
void function(IntegerArray const&);

/// \overload brief A function
 void function(FloatArray const&);
```

This will help doxygen to separately document them

Comment: That is not at all necessary, and also doesn't solve the problem. Thanks, though!